# Snowflake SQL to get get last 5 Sundays

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Seeking help for a way to achieve something like:

select getdates(3,"sunday");

output: 2020-09-13, 2020-09-06, 2020-08-30

Comment: Have you considered adding a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the solution myself, the problem was not defined properly.

Based on the given input, need to pull the last 3 same days of the week

Solution:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you.

This was my solution:

```
WITH DAY_SUNDAY AS (           
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1*SEQ4(), CURRENT_DATE()) AS DATE, DAYNAME(DATE) AS DAY_NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DAY_NAME ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RANK
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => (100000) ))
WHERE 1=1
AND UPPER(DAY_NAME) = 'SUN'
  )
SELECT DATE
FROM DAY_SUNDAY
WHERE 1=1
AND RANK<6;
```

I hope it helps you